# Can I register a static callback class in a static function in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to register `MediaProjection.Callback` for `mMediaProjection` in order to stop `MediaRecorder` in static function `StartRecord`.

I defined the class `MediaProjectionCallback` as `private static` and I provided  the parameter `mMediaRecorder` to it.
Is the following code right? or is there the better code?

```
public class RecordHelper {
    public static void StartRecord(Context mContext,RecordArg mRecordArg,int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

        MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) mContext.getSystemService
                (Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);


        MediaProjection  mMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);


        MediaProjectionCallback mMediaProjectionCallback = new MediaProjectionCallback(mMediaRecorder);
        mMediaProjection.registerCallback(mMediaProjectionCallback, null);
        mMediaRecorder.start();
    }




    private static class MediaProjectionCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {

        MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

        public  MediaProjectionCallback(MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder){
            this.mMediaRecorder=mMediaRecorder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            mMediaRecorder.stop();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: *Is the following code right?* - does it work?

Comment: Complie is OK, because  my code is not finished, so I can't test if it work